# ModuleNotFoundError when registering django app

Tags: django

I'm getting an error when I include my app in the settings.py file using `<app>.apps.PagesConfig`.  I'm in a virtual environment, have the project and app installed, and the app has an `__init__.py` inside.  If I just register it as `<app>`, it works, but not with the full `<app>.apps.PagesConfig`  See code and error below.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app_test.apps.PagesConfig',
]
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_test.apps.PagesConfig'; 'app_test.apps' is not a package
```

Comment: can you show the folder and file structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'app_test.apps.AppTestConfig',
```

this would be the one that you need to put in the settings, the Class Name which is there in the apps.py not some random name

Comment: That did it.  I had the wrong name before Config.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried.  Says my reputation score is not high enough yet.  I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file `apps.py` which would contain a class `PagesConfig` to make this work. For example `app_test/apps.py` could look like:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PagesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'My pages'
```

See the [Django application documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-authors).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be created automatically.  My ```apps.py``` file in the ```app_test``` app shows: 

```from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppTestConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_test'```